# MongoDB - Design efficient way to calculate result

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, design-patterns, architecture

I am using Java, Spring-Boot and for db a mongodb. In mongo I have `human` collection structure like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5eaf79f4bce37709f84f6b03"
  },
  "claimNo": 123
  "xrays": [
    "xray1",
    "xray2",
    "xray3"
  ],
  "xray_details": {
    "xray1": {},
    "xray2": {},
    "xray3": {},
  },
  "claimResult": "A"
}
```

`xrays` object contains names of the xrays. `xray_details` contains detail information about each xray.
So it is something like once we create this document initially; `xray_details` and `claimResult` doesn't contain any information. We get information as soon as it gets ready so e.g. for xray2 we may get some info but for xray3 and xray1 we may get info 15 mins later. What we need to do is that once we have some info then we need to calculate and update `claimResult`.

**Detailed Explanation:**
In `xray_details` we get info for `xray2` but `xray1` and `xray3` aren't available then we take into account only `xray2` and update `claimResult`. As soon as we get some other xray information i.e. `xray1` then we would use `xray1`, `xray2` to calculate `claimResult` and once at later point we get `xray3` then again we need to check/confirm whether do we already have info to use `xray1`, `xray2`,`xray3` to calculate `claimResult`.

**Problem:**
At this stage we are making a scheduler to calculate result but that isn't efficient and we need that, as soon as the information is available we take into account the previous completed ones and calculate the result again. Don't know whether solutions like kafka can work in this context or not but feel free to provide your valuable feedback/suggestions on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, scheduler cannot be efficient here.

Why scheduler is not the best:

---

1. It may need to poll for the details inefficiently when there is no change
2. It will affect the other requests pending on the db when it polls inefficiently.

What is best:

---

As you suspected, Kafka is the best fit. I prefer Kafka over other messaging system because Kafka is `durable` and you can have many consumers in single consumer group to `process the messages in parallel`.

Whenever a new entry is entered, publish a message to Kafka topic. Convert your scheduler application logic to message driven. It will automatically process new messages when it is published.

---

Let's say Application1,2,3 inserts these xray1,2,3 details. Here the problem is calculation of claimResult. So when an application updates these X-ray details, it has to produce a message.

Consumer should pick that message and calculates claimResult and update it.

Comment: One more thing we could do is use mongo triggers, but somehow we found it isn't durable as most of the time it didn't triggered at all or failed for whatever reason. For Kafka I believe it could become a little complex solution but anyhow I would like to listen so could you explain a little more in detail? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Which part of Kafka you want to know more? producer/consumer/infra? @iCurious

Comment: I am not very familiar with Kafka but if you could provide the brief solution design then I can figure out the rest. Just to give a more understanding that application is message driven so application listens topic and inserts  in db. Then other consumer listens to other topic and when gets detail info it updates the document

Comment: oh i didn't got any notification for this. Thanks! this seems interesting. At the moment we are working on a temporary solution but i'll check this out and share more details. Thanks!

Comment: What is that temp solution? Can you explain little about that? If my answer is helpful, can you  approve/upvote/both too.

Comment: temp solution is the scheduler for calculating results. Also manual one is their where we initiate it to calculate results. But again this needs to be revisit.